# Json schema file will not execute in BigQuery Python API

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I am having an issue with Bigquery Python API.  Here is the stack trace when I execute my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createTable.py", line 17, in <module>
    open_schema()
  File "createTable.py", line 12, in open_schema
    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
    ...
    "Schema items must either be fields or compatible "
ValueError: Schema items must either be fields or compatible mapping representations.
```

The script is very simple, open a schema file and create the table:

```
   from google.cloud import bigquery
   # Construct a BigQuery client object.
   client = bigquery.Client()
   table_id = "project-py-290522:bq_dts.bq-test"
       
   def open_schema():
       with open("hcl-schema.json","r", encoding = "utf-8") as fName:
           schema = fName.readlines()
       
           table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
           print(repr(table))
           client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
       
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       open_schema()
       
   print("Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id))
```

When I execute the schema in the console and the CLI, the table is created perfectly as is.  How can the console and CLI execute the create table but chokes in the API. I have searched and searched and have not found an answer.  Can someone help?

Here is the schema stored in the hcl-schema.json file. I've shortened the attribut list for brevity, but otherwise intact:

```
    [  
      {
        "name":"user_id",
        "type":"STRING",
        "mode":"NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name":"msg_version",
        "type":"STRING",
        "mode":"REQUIRED"           
      },
      {
        "name":"APIStreamData",
        "type":"RECORD",
        "mode":"REQUIRED",
        "fields":
        [
          {
            "name":"msg_version",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"REQUIRED"
          },
          {
            "name":"streams",
            "type":"RECORD",
            "mode":"REPEATED",
            "fields":
            [
                {
                  "name":"length",
                  "type":"STRING",
                  "mode":"REQUIRED"
                },                      
                {
                  "name":"cached",
                  "type":"STRING",
                  "mode":"NULLABLE"
                },  
              {
                "name":"track",
                "type":"RECORD",
                "mode":"REQUIRED",
                "fields":
                [
                  {
                    "name":"msg_version",
                    "type":"STRING",
                    "mode":"REQUIRED"
                  },
                  {
                    "name":"track_id",
                    "type":"STRING",
                    "mode":"REQUIRED"
                  }
                ]
              }    
    
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Thanks

Dazed and confused

Comment: Maybe something with file encoding... Try printing out the `schema` variable before `table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The below documentation i am referring shows the schema to be specified like below in Python
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition

schema = [bigquery.SchemaField("full_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED")]

I tried with below JSON and Code, this works fine. I think the json you provided has RECORD inside RECORD so we need to handle accordingly

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = "my-project.mock_dataset.bq-test"

def open_schema():
            
    bigquerySchema = []
    bigqueryfieldSchema = []
    with open('test.json') as f:
        bigqueryColumns = json.load(f)
        print(bigqueryColumns)
        for col in bigqueryColumns:
            if col['type'] != 'RECORD':
                print(col['name'])
                bigquerySchema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(col['name'], col['type'],mode=col['mode']))
            else:
                for colfield in col['fields']:
                    bigqueryfieldSchema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(colfield['name'], colfield['type'],colfield['mode']))
                print(bigqueryfieldSchema)
                print(col['fields'])
                bigquerySchema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(col['name'], col['type'],col['mode'],'',bigqueryfieldSchema))
        print(bigquerySchema)

    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=bigquerySchema)
    print(repr(table))
    client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
    print("Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_schema()
```

```
 [  
      {
        "name":"user_id",
        "type":"STRING",
        "mode":"NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name":"msg_version",
        "type":"STRING",
        "mode":"REQUIRED"           
      },
      {
        "name":"APIStreamData",
        "type":"RECORD",
        "mode":"REQUIRED",
        "fields":
        [
          {
            "name":"msg_version",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"REQUIRED"
          },
          {
             "name":"track_id",
             "type":"STRING",
             "mode":"REQUIRED"
          }
       ]
      }
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was a huge help.  Now I need to translate that into a recursive dive into the json.  I don't know how many nested records I will run into

Comment: Glad that it works for you. I think based on levels of nesting you have we have to change the script accordingly.

Comment: Well, on the surface it appears to be working.  Howerver, after a few more failures I have discovered that i also haqve to account for the code page.  But...

Comment: I think it helped you to solve your problem in a way that instead of passing  the json as schema we need to pass it as SchemaField Object  while using Python API? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I just encountered this problem and it seems that a simple dict representation of the json file works for me. See my other answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a dict representation of the json file, not a string as in the original question:

```
with open("schema.json") as json_file:
    schema_dict = json.load(json_file)
    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema_dict)
    table = client.create_table(table)
```